# How to style ng-content, ::ng-deep not working

Tags: angular

I am trying to style content inside `<ng-content>` in anuglar2

```
<au-fa-input >
   <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="email" #input>
 </au-fa-input>
```

Inside au-fa-input component css i try

```
  :host /deep/ input{
   display:none
  }
```

OR

```
::ng-deep input{
   display:none
  }
```

But this is not working

Comment: It should work. Can you please try create a reproduction using stackblitz.com?

Answer (score 0):

i think /deep/ does not apply directly on ng-content and ng-template, it does on nested component for example so you have to create a div with a class that contain you element and try something like that:

```
<ng-content>
   <div class="deepClass">
     <au-fa-input >
         <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="email" #input>
     </au-fa-input>
   </div>
</ng-content>
```

and css

```
.deepClass /deep/ input {
   display:none
}
```